# How to replace square brackets [] in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, customer and customer_products, in customer table, i have image column, and storing data as [25] which this 25 is id from customer_products column
id,

Here i am trying both data customer and customer_products using left join and remove [] from 25

Here is my sql Query.

```
"SELECT c.*, cp.* 
 FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
      customer_products cp 
      ON c.[image]=cp.id 
WHERE status='L'";
```

Comment: If the question is about MySQL, please.dont tag SQL Server. They are completely different products.

Comment: @Larnu, SQL query was also related to Mysql server

Comment: "MySQL Server"? That sounds like an odd portmento of MySQl and SQL Server. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat()` function to get the same format on `customer_products` column:

```
SELECT c.*, cp.* 
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
     customer_products cp ON
     c.image = concat('[',cp.id,']')
WHERE status='L';
```

You could also use `trim()` function to remove `[]` signs from `customer` column:

```
SELECT c.*, cp.* 
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
     customer_products cp ON
     trim(trailing ']' from trim(leading '[' from c.image)) = cp.id
WHERE status='L';
```

---

**As a general rule** you should change your data so that numbers are being stored as numbers and include a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` to properly address any issues that you have right now and be able to fully use the power of indexes to improve performance of your searches without using functional indexes.

That said, if you want to modify your data to ensure it's being properly stored, use `UPDATE` to fix invalid "numbers".

Comment: G, Thanks for the answer, I have tried using replace string, but i am getting syntax error.

Comment: I don't use replace. Please try the code I've provided and if any problem arises post the error message.